# React Native: issue with flex layout

Tags: flexbox, react-native

I'm trying to make a simple view with 2 subviews - v1, v2 aligned horizontally and each taking 50% of the screen width.

[image]

To achieve this, I'm using the following code:

```
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
   <View style={{flex:1}}>
   <View style={{flex:1}}>
</View>
```

I've also tried playing with other attributes- `flexWrap`, `justifyContent`.

However, everytime the views get stacked one after the other and doesn't take 50% of the screen. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: The actual piece of code I'm using:

```
  <View>
    <Text style={styles.place}>New Delhi</Text>
    <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
      <DayTimeComponent style={{flex:1}}/>
      <DayTimeComponent style={{flex:1}}/>
    </View>
    </View>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this easily using [react-native-easy-grid](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/react-native-easy-grid)

**Code:**

```
import { Col, Row, Grid } from "react-native-easy-grid";

export default class StackOverflow extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex:1}}>
       <Grid>
        <Col style={{backgroundColor:'yellow',alignItems:'center',justifyContent:'center'}}><Text>v1</Text></Col>
        <Col style={{backgroundColor:'green',alignItems:'center',justifyContent:'center'}}><Text>v2</Text></Col>
       </Grid>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

You can also create custom layouts, for eg: if you need a 75%-25% split then all you need to do is

```
<Col size={75}></Col>
<Col size={25}></Col>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set "flex:1" on **both** the container views. Like so:

```
<View style={{flex:1}}>
    <Text style={styles.place}>New Delhi</Text>
    <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', flex:1}}>
        <DayTimeComponent style={{flex:1}}/>
        <DayTimeComponent style={{flex:1}}/>
    </View>
</View>
```

Comment: I updated the answer. You need to set the flex property on all the parent components for it to work.